# Parsing CSV to list of tuples without using CSV module

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I'm working on an assignment in a Python class at the moment, and one particular part is asking me to import a CSV file (with data in the format of "text, number, number, ..., number, number") without the use of the CSV module (or any modules at all, in fact), and return the data as a list of tuples, in this format:

```
[(’Text’, [number, number, ..., number, number]),
(’Text’, [number, number, ..., number, number]),
.....]
```

I think I've got the actual process of opening the file and beginning to read it line by line correct (see snippet below), but I'm not quite sure on how to proceed with regards to parsing each line into the format needed.

```
def load_data(filename):
    open(filename)
    for line in filename
```

I've tried searching for help but the only help I can seem to find says to just use the CSV module (which isn't particularly helpful because we're not allowed to import any modules bar the math library) or has the data being input and/or output in a different format. If anyone could give me some pointers as to what I should be doing or where I can start that would be super helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: Per the suggestion made by @dotancohen here is some sample data:

```
Slow Loris, 21.72, 29.3, 20.08, 29.98, 29.85, 26.22, 29.68
Ocelot, 57.51, 47.59, 55.89, 47.15, 46.71, 51.7, 46.68, 54.54
Tiger, 75.0, 82.43, 112.11, 89.93, 103.19, 80.6, 113.44, 75.55, 102.29, 108.1, 98.84, 101.48, 77.75, 98.57, 70.31, 78.28, 80.18
```

Also below is what I have at the moment as a potential solution:

```
def load_data(filename):
    open(filename) as file
    output = []
    for line in filename
        temp_list = line.split(',')
        temp_item = temp_list.pop(0)
        tup = (temp_item, temp_list)
        output.append(tup)
    return output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV files usually have the lines delimited with either a comma or a tab, so in the **naive** case this will give you the different fields:

```
for line in filename:
    fields = line.split(',')  # For comma-delimited files
    # - or -
    fields = line.split('\t') # For tab-delimited files
```

However, we can seldom allow ourselves to be so naive. CSV files have, among others, the following caveats:

1. **Quoted values:** This is a legal field in CSV: "I think, therefore I am". You need to be careful not to split on the comma inside the quotes. Newines can also appear in quoted values, so you cannot reliably use `for line in filename` naively.
2. **Escaped quotes in quoted values:** This is a legal field in CSV: "She said\"I think so\"". This means that your state machine for matching per-character in-quoted out-quoted state needs a lookback mechanism as well.

Thus, to reliably parse CSV files you need a state machine that saves state across lines in files. There are horrible surprises along the way, such as dealing with Unicode CSV files in Python 2 (hint: if you have non-ASCII text, use Python 3). There are also small surprises, like some applications putting a space after the comma delimiter or not adding commas for blank fields at the end of the line.

Therefore, if you are to **accept CSV files as input from your users, use the CSV module**. However, if you can control the input (i.e. you produce it from another script) then you can use the naive `line.split('\t')` method.

**As per the sample data posted by the OP**, we see that he does not not have to worry about quoted fields, but his CSV source is in fact adding erroneous spaces after the comma delimiters. Thus, this is the code specific to the OP's situation:

```
for line in filename:
    fields = line.split(',')
    fields = [x.strip() for x in fields] # Remove whitespace
```

Comment: Right, so I'll be using line.split(',') since my file is entirely comma separated. While I can't control the input, we have been given the two CSV files that the program will be tested against and they both have the same consistent formatting with nothing like quoted values, escaped quotes or non-unicode chars (although we are using Python 3). Should I split the text into a separate variable then rejoin the text to the numbers as a tuple? That should give the the output I'm looking for, right?

Comment: @RandosaurusRex - That looks like a good approach to work on for a while. You may well finish it without further help but if you try that design and have trouble come back and ask for detailed help. I suspect you'll be fine from here in but no shame if you do encounter a tripping point between here and the end.

Comment: @RandosaurusRex: I would prefer to see the example file before giving a yes or a no, can you please add a few sample lines to the question? Thanks.

Comment: @RandosaurusRex: See my edited answer which addresses your data.

Comment: @dotancohen wait, won't that remove the space in "Slow Loris"? Hmm.

Comment: Actually, unless I insert it after my temp_list.pop(0) command and before merging them into a tuple, that would retain the space in "Slow Loris" but still remove the erroneous spaces in the number list

Comment: Yep, that worked, thank you very much @dotancohen :)

Answer (score 1):

One key concept to look at would be [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html).

Splitting a CSV up based on the commas seems to be an important part of the puzzle, don't you agree.

Comment: So I should be using something along the lines of line.split(',')? If I do that, should I do something like split the list into two sublists, one with the text and the other with the numbers, then somehow link them as a single list item?

Answer (score 0):

This is the `data` in the `CSV` file:

```
text1   1   2   3   4   5
text2   6   7   8   9   10
text3   11  12  13  14  15
```

You can use `setdefault` and `zip` to achieve the output you need *in Python2*.

```
d = {}
with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        for i in line[1:]:
            key = (line[0])
            d.setdefault(key, []).append(int(i))

x = sorted(d.keys())
y = sorted(d.values())
lst = zip(x,y)
print (lst)
```

Output:

```
[('text1', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), ('text2', [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), ('text3', [11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]
```

In *Python3* you have to replace this line `lst = zip(x,y)` with `lst = list(zip(x,y))`

Answer (score 0):

**mycsv file contents : (data.csv)**

```
"New Zealand,46 - 15,Argentina ,01/06/1987,31"
"France,70 - 12,Zimbabwe ,02/06/1987,58"
"Wales,40 - 9,Canada ,03/06/1987,31"
"England,34 - 6,USA ,03/06/1987,28"
"New Zealand,49 - 6,Wales ,14/06/1987,43"
"New Zealand,70 - 6,Italy ,22/05/1987,64"
"Canada,37 - 4,Tonga ,24/05/1987,33"
"New Zealand,74 - 13,FIJI ,27/05/1987,61"
"France,55 - 12,Romania ,28/05/1987,43"
"England,60 - 7,Japan ,30/05/1987,53"
```

**code to read csv without csv module & store each line into list :**

```
fo = open("data.csv", 'r')
data = fo.read()
fo.close()   

games=[]
data = data.splitlines()
for line in data:
    games.append(line.split(","))
    
print(games)
```